Is mismatching trailing slash in hreflang a problem for indexing spiders like Googlebot?

I got a Joomla 4 website.
there's a .htaccess rule redirecting URLs ending with / to version without slash, also www. is removed
I'm using Aimy Canonical plugin for rel="canonical" URLs. Can't configure the non-premium version to include slash, it always adds links without it.

I noticed that the German URLs aren't really well placed for searches with German IP, only for German searches with Polish IP. Then I noticed that hreflangs have trailing slashes, mismatching the rest of the URL related aspects of the website. Example:
<link href="https://lenkraddesign.eu/de/" rel="alternate" hreflang="de-DE">
<link href="https://lenkraddesign.eu/de" rel="canonical">

I don't know if and how much of a problem this is for SEO. I used some tools like http://hreflangchecker.com to verify this and it says that there's cannonical mismatch and not listing itself problem. I'm asking mainly because this is not easily changeable in Joomla.
Are those serious problems that need fixing? How does Google handle such slight mismatches?
